# Html Agility Pack doesnt 'save' changes. Need to reload content

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I'm converting regular HTML snippets to proper html for e-mails.

this involves changing `<p>` and `<ul>` elements to divs and tables.

```
public static string getMailifiedHtml(string html) 
{
    //add spacing front and back to P and UL elements
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(html);

    HtmlNode spacer = doc.CreateElement("div");
    spacer.Attributes.Add("style", "font-size:10px;");
    spacer.InnerHtml = "&nbsp;";

    doc.DocumentNode.AppendChild(spacer);

    doc.LoadHtml(doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml);

    var pulolnodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p|/ul|/ol");
    if (pulolnodes != null) {
        foreach (HtmlNode tb in pulolnodes) {
            //tb.PrependChild(spacer);
            tb.ParentNode.InsertBefore(spacer, tb);
        }
    }

    doc.LoadHtml(doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml);

    var pnodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p");
    if (pnodes != null) {
        foreach (HtmlNode tb in pnodes) {
            string value = tb.InnerHtml;
            HtmlNode lbl = doc.CreateElement("div");
            lbl.InnerHtml = value;
            tb.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(lbl, tb);
        }
    }
   ...
```

first thing I do is add a spacer behind the html.
I then have to reload the html.
then I add spacers in front of all P/UL/OL elements
then I reload it again, and then change all P elements to DIV's

funny thing is, I'm adding the spacers on the outside.
so

```
<p>content</p>
```

becomes

```
<div ... >&nbsp;</div><p>content</p>
```

when I try to select all P elements after that

```
var pnodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p");
```

this finds 0 results... but the P's are still there?
the only fix I found is reloading the whole doc. But that can't be the way of doing things?

Answer (score 1):

you should explicitly save the document using Save method

```
doc.Save(filepath);
```